# Create Custom Footer in marketing cloud that switches between two different Preference Center

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I  need to create a custom footer that will dynamically be populated, If the subscriber key is a Salesforce ID (starts with 003(contact), 005(user) or 00q(lead), 001(account) AND it will always be 18 digits, does not contain @ symbol, then we need to display the custom preference center URL 1. If the subscriber key is not a Salesforce ID, i.e. it has an email address then the Custom Preference Center URL 2 must be displayed.

Solution Which I'm thinking:-

1. Created 2 HTML content that will have a code of Footer, where I'll mention the URL of Profile Centers.
2. Use those HTML content in Dynamic Content Block-based and apply rules on D.E chosen to show which HTML content needs to be displayed. If the Subscriber key contains 003 or 005 it should display HTML content that has preference Center URL 1. If the Subscriber Key contains @ or .com it should display HTML Content that has a preference center 2 URL.

I have a question can a subscriber Key column hold Salesforce ID and Email Address as a value ?? which we will use to create a rule in the dynamic content block?

Someone else has some other alternative solution to this requirement??

Modified Code:

```
%%[
SET @SFIDregEx = "^00[135Q][a-zA-Z0-9]"
SET @EmailRegEx = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})$"
SET @subKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
SET @Email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
SET @match1 = RegExMatch(@subKey, @SFIDregEx1, 0)
SET @match2 = RegExMatch(@Email, @EmailRegEx, 0)
SET @len1 = length(@match1)
SET @len2 = length(@match2)
IF @len1 > 0 THEN
SET @redirect = "https://google.com" -----// example
ENDIF
IF @len2 >0 THEN
SET @redirect = "https://trailhead.com" -----//example
ELSE
SET @redirect = "https://yahoo.com" ------//example
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Hi Abishek. The purpose of this community is not to provide turnkey solutions based on requirements. I will advise you to look into Ampscript and especially RegExMatch function. Try this regex: ^00[135Q][a-zA-Z0-9]{12,15} - Please provide code example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hey Lukas, thanks for the comment, I've created the solution based on creating a dynamic content block. I just want to know, for now, can we have values as Email Id and Salesforce Id in the Subscriber Key column? which I'm using to create a rule in the Dynamic content block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend using RegEx to identify whether or not your subscriber key is from one of the four valid Salesforce objects, and if not - default to a fallback solution:

```
%%[
SET @regEx = "^00[135Q][a-zA-Z0-9]{12,15}"
SET @subKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
SET @match = RegExMatch(@subKey, @regEx, 0, "IgnoreCase")
SET @len = length(@match)
IF @len > 0 THEN
SET @redirect = "https://example.com/unsubSalesforce"
ELSE
SET @redirect = "https://example.com/unsubOther"
ENDIF
]%%
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@redirect)=%%">Unsubscribe</a>
```

You might want to pass some parameters to the landing pages, in that case these should be added to `@redirect` using `CONCAT` function.

Alternatively, if you want to fetch the entire separate content block for each option, instead of just replacing the URL, you can fetch the entire contentblock using [ContentBlockByKey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbykey.htm):

```
%%[
SET @regEx = "^00[135Q][a-zA-Z0-9]{12,15}"
SET @subKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
SET @match = RegExMatch(@subKey, @regEx, 0, "IgnoreCase")
SET @len = length(@match)
IF @len > 0 THEN
ContentBlockbyKey("unsubSalesforce")
ELSE
ContentBlockbyKey("unsubOther")
ENDIF
]%%
```

ContentBlockbyKey function references the customer key of a content block, which you can see under preferences:

[image]

You can paste the code above into the custom footer field, under Setup > Company Preferences, like this:

[image]

However, I would advise against it, as it will both be added to the transactional as well as commercial sends. Adding the footer to the template used for commercial emails is IMHO a better option.

---

You always need to reference the subscriber key - in both RegExMatch functions, as applying the email matching regex on the email field will always evaluate TRUE:

```
SET @match2 = RegExMatch(@subKey, @EmailRegEx, 0).
```

Also, use ELSEIF in your tests:

```
IF @len1 > 0 
THEN 
SET @redirect = "https://google.com" -----// example 
ELSEIF @len2 >0 
THEN 
SET @redirect = "https://trailhead.com" -----//example 
ELSE 
SET @redirect = "https://yahoo.com" ------//example 
ENDIF
```

Comment: Hey @Lukas Lunaow, thanks for the above the solution, it looks like I'm able to achieve what I'm looking for. But I'm not really sure where do I need to apply this formula? actually I'm new to Salesforce Marketing and still learning concepts here. could you please guide me how to use this? Like do I need to create an HTML content block or needs to be applied directly in Footer under Admin > Account Setting. Thanks, Abhishek

Comment: @abhishekverma - I have updated my answer accordingly. Remember to accept/upvote if it has been helpful

Comment: Hey @lukas It worked well and I've created a Code snippet and used that in my email template. I've also modified your code a bit but it's giving me an error, could you please help me out with that. Also, I'm trying to share the code here but getting error :( pasting code in my main question box on top, please have a look and suggest me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you post the error medssage here, @abhishekverma

Comment: Hi @Lukas, The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.An IF statement is not closed with the required ENDIF statement.

Comment: @abhishekverma - this is quite obvious.... Every time you open your IF statement, you need to close it with ENDIF. In case you also use ELSE, you need to have ENDIF after the code which is executed when IF condition is not met.

Comment: Hey @Lukas, I've closed the IF statement It worked but It's redirecting  me to only one URL(trailhead in this case) even though my subscriber Key is Salesforce Id or it's email Id or it's other, please check the code in the main question

Comment: @abhishekverma - updated my answer with relevant code

Comment: It worked graciously, thank you @Lucas. I've learned something new today in the Marketing cloud world. Thanks for the support.